# Tree panel error in extjs4

Tags: javascript

In ExtJS4, a tree panel was created with Ext.tree.Panel. When it is clicked multiple times (around 8 to 16) to expand or collapse the tree nodes, It gives error 'event' is null or not an object at line 10708 of ext-all-debug.js. On each click it creats another node below the clicked one. This problem is seen only in IE 8 where as same code are working fine in FirFox. Can anyone fix this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after excluding all references of *.js files except bootstrap.js and project related *.js from index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

On further analysis:
A first look into `bootstrap.js` informs us that it automatically loads either `ext-all.js` OR `ext-debug-all.js` based on certain conditions.

If either of these files are being included / linked in your JSP, you will face this issue.